# How would I join a string continued over 2 lines in Python using Regex?

Tags: python, regex, ldap

**I have an LDAP Schema file (Text file written in BASH) read into a List in Python. My Code:**

```
LDAP_SCHEMA_LIST = []
LDAP_CORE_LIST = []
LDAP_CORE_DICT = {}
LDAP_CORE_FILE = '/../../../schema-core'
with open (LDAP_CORE_FILE) as LDAP_FILE_OBJECT:
    LDAP_SCHEMA_LIST = LDAP_FILE_OBJECT.readlines()
for line in LDAP_SCHEMA_LIST:
    if re.match("[A-Za-z0-9]+:", line)
        print(line.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
dn: cn=<OU>, cn=schema, cn=config
objectClass: schemaConfig
cn: <OU>
objectAttribute: {n} ( 1.2.3.4.5.6 Name Address Us
 er Just making up some more data to fill 1.1..1.1
  .111.131.111 SINGLE-VALUE )
objectAttribute: More Plaintext Data
 This would be the string above continued on this line
  1212 this is another continued line from the string
objectAttribute: etc...
```

I would like to be able to create a regex search pattern or sed/awk statement to **match the two lines of the continued string and join them as one line**. For Example:

```
dn: cn=<OU>, cn=schema, cn=config
objectClass: schemaConfig
cn: <OU>
objectAttribute: {n} ( 1.2.3.4.5.6 Name Address User Just making up some more data to fill...
objectAttribute: More Plaintext Data This would be the string above continued on this line 1212 this...
```

Comment: Use the `re.DOTALL` flag to allow `.` to match newlines.

Comment: That helps with searching the newlines but I'm still unsure how to write the regex pattern OR how to join the lines together.

Comment: My Code So Far...`if line.startswith("objectAttribute: {n}": if re.match(regex_pattern, line, re.DOTALL): print(line.strip())`

Comment: Since you're reading the file one line at a time, you can't use a regexp to match across multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

Save each line in a variable before printing it. When you read a line, check if it begins with a space, indicating that it's a continuation of the previous line. If it does, concatenate the line to the variable. Otherwise, print the saved variable and assign the variable with the current line.

At the end, print the last saved line.

```
saved_line = None
for line in LDAP_SCHEMA_LIST:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith(" "):
        saved_line += line
    else:
        if saved_line:
            print(saved_line)
        saved_line = line
if saved_line:
    print(saved_line)
```